# How to display images from database in a while loop

Tags: php, html, css

Beginnger-ish PHP/MYSQL Coder here, I'm creating a category browse page, and I have to display 50 images from a mysql database called "inventory". I generated the links through the while loop, but no clue on  how I'm supposed to generate the images in succession without 50 lines of `<img src`. The way I would like to generate it is:

Image

Link (on new line),
image2 (on new line),
link2 (on new line),
and etc...

My images are numbered from 1.jpg to 50.jpg.

```php
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql) or die("Bad Query: $sql");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<a href = 'details.php?ID={$row['Item_Number']}'>{$row['Item_Name']}</a><br>\n";

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is the column that holds the image names?

Comment: Do you have images with names in sequence from 1 to 50?

Comment: the column is called "jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed the point there then you can simply add the `img` tag to the generated HTML in the loop - selecting the appropriate path and the data from the db.

```
<?php

    include 'connection.php';
    $sql = 'select `jpg`, `item_name`, `item_number` from `products`';


    $result = mysqli_query( $mysql, $sql ) or die("bad query: $sql");
    if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {

        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {

            # Ensure that the path below is correct
            echo "
                <img src='/path/to/images/{$row['jpg']}' alt='{$row['item_name']}' />
                <br />
                <a href='details.php?id={$row['item_number']}'>{$row['item_name']}</a>
                <br />
                <br />";

        }
    }
?>
```